# Why does Web page fail to use downloaded sqlite3 database?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webserver

```
var db; //global variable

$(document).ready(function () {
    // This is the recommended code for a Web page to download 
    // an sqlite3 database:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/PathTo/Database.db', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
        db = new SQL.Database(uInt8Array);

        // My code here
        fNowUseDownloadedDatabase();
    };
    xhr.send();
}
function fNowUseDownloadedDatabase() {
    // Remember, db is a global variable.
    var a = db.exec("SELECT 'name', 'sql' FROM 'sqlite_master' WHERE type='table';");
    var iLen = a.length;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < iLen; i++) {
        console.log(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Instead of having 3 tables, the database has none. I know the path to the database is correct, otherwise I'd get a 404 error. Also, if I pass db into my fNowUseDownloadedDatabase function, it is an empty database. But on the server it has data. Somehow it is being downloaded with data but then replaced by an empty new database. Why not?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200976/sqlite-in-chrome

Comment: No help at all.